# YouTube embed video with WKWebView starts playing randomly

Tags: ios, swift

My app has 4 tabs, each tab is a collection view cell. In the second tab, the video tab there is another collection view that displays Youtube videos with WKwebView. All works perfectly, except that when I leave the main view controller with the 4 tabs and then I come back to it, the video that was previously playing (and had been stopped) starts playing suddenly at full screen.
I have no idea why.
This happens when I use the following url "https://youtube.com/embed/(embedCode!)", while it does not if I upload the full YouTube page and not only the video embed.
[image: Main view controller with the 4 tabs]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a third party library from GitHub:
Swift-YouTube-Player